# (ORA-40573) Updating Table using JSON_OBJECT_T elements?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I am trying to update fields of a table using a JSON_OBJECT_T's elements. However, I am getting

```
ORA-40573: Invalid use of PL/SQL JSON object type.
```

Example:

```
metadata := JSON_OBJECT_T.parse(json_clob)

insert into catimage (
            OBJECTID,
            OBJTYPE,

            values(
            sde.gdb_util.next_rowid('CISCAT', 'CATIMAGE'),
            metadata.get_String('objtype'), --OBJTYPE
            )
```

I don't get the error if I set each field I require from the JSON_OBJECT_T as a variable. Is that the only way?

Thank you.
Jon

Comment: Please edit the question and show the table DDL and the definition of the variables you are using

Comment: The example code is sufficient to describe the issue. The ORA issue is described here: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2490027_1.html . I don't have the permissions to view the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ORA issue has yet to be patched. Workaround as suggested by the article is to manually set all variables before insert.

Comment: 1 year later, has this been resolved? I still encounter this error message, also when I use get_array('key').to_string()

Comment: 2 years later and still not solved

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped to view the table DDL and variable definition.

However, given the limited information shared in the question, you might be hitting a bug related to insertion of JSON objects using PLSQL.

The suggested workaround is to put the data into a string variable and inserting the data into table.
Hope it helps